# How to post HTML body on tumblr from iOS?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, post, tumblr

I would like to format my post on tumblr. For that, I am trying to post `HTML` as text post on tumblr.

Here is what I am doing.

If I use the following html, then it is getting posted properly on tumblr wall.

```
postbody=@"body=<p>Hi Taruni </br> <b><i>Neema</p>"
```

and I am getting proper format on my tumblr wall.

But, if I add anchor tags or img tags, then its not working.

```
postbody=@"body=<p>Hi Taruni </br> <b><i>Neema<img src=\"http://www.google.com\"></p>"
```

If I post with the above postBody, then I am getting following response

`{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you read the "msg" and "status" values in the response? That's the problem.

Comment: Error 401 is described here: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html

Comment: @occulus.. I understood. But, If I use the first postBody content then I am not getting any error. I am getting 201 as response. 201 response means, "the post is successfully posted". But, why I am getting 401 if I use the second postBody ?? What is the mistake I made in that content?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the `src=""` value set to an URL and not an actual image?

Comment: Noo.. instead of img.. if I use anchor tag also.. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Are the quotes all characters who need to be escaped? What about the slashes in the src attribute value?

Comment: Yes, I am also doing this.. `[postbody stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]`